Is a binomial of Chi-Square or t test the correct test to compare dichotomous variables?
You have an ML model that outputs 100,000 out of a million observations of a dichotomous variable 0 or 1. You want to see whether the distribution of the outputted 100,000 observations of the model is similar to the 1 mil. You apply the model 3 times let's call them A B and C and you get 3 sets of 100,000 observations. You want to test them to have the same distribution as the original 1,000,000. You apply a T test between the three of 100,000 and the 1,000,000 then a Chi Square between the 3 of 100,000 and the 1,000,000 and then a binomial test.  The t test and the binomial test agree that B is similar to the whole set and A and C are different but Chi Square says that only C is similar. So, which of the models approximated the 1,000,000 rows best?

Are you trying to determine the predictive performance of your model? Perhaps there are better metrics than the method you used, but additional details about the context, the dataset, and the model would be useful to suggest you something. In addition, what do you mean exactly when you say "The t test and the binomial test agree that B is similar to the whole set and A and C are different but Chi Square says that only C is similar."?

I want to see how close the distribution of each of the 100,000 observations is to the original data. By agree I mean both tests have a p value that is significant.

"I want to see how close the distribution of each of the 100,000 observations is to the original data". But why do you want to do that, ultimately? And what do you mean by significant? Can you share the output of the tests? Maybe they do not disagree as much as you think, but hard to tell without seeing the details.

You are trying to compare 4 binomial proportions. But can you clarify exactly what tests you are using, and how? E.g. you mention a t-test (for proportions); but that is not correct, you should use a z-test (t is not appropriate as the variance is not independent of the mean). You mention a $\chi^2$ test; but is that a series of 2x2 tests, of a single 4x2? You mention a binomial test, but are you computing 4 binomial CI's? Or running a Fisher-exact? If Fisher, is that a seiries of 2x2 tests, or a single 4x2 omnibus test?

When running a Chi square I am running 3 2x2 tests (a series of test) . For each A, B and C comparing with the general population. I am doing so for all others.

It seems that your basic problem is that you have 4 binomial proportions, and want to compare them (are they, statistically, the same?).
One particularity of the problem is that, one of the 4 is the ground truth (it is the complete population); there is no sampling error (uncertainty) for that 4th one, only for the first 3.
And the basic question is what is the "best" (right?) way to do this comparison?
You mention a t-test. That would be a good choice for comparting means of 2 samples coming from normal distribution (better than a z-test). For normally distributed data, the mean and variance are independent. But here we are comparing binomially distributed data; and in that case, the mean and variance are correlated (the mean is $np$, and the variance is $np(1-p)$, where p is the Bernoulli probability, and $n$ is the number of Bernoulli events). So here, a t-test is not a correct option.
Having said this, given you rather (very?) large sample sizes, the difference between z and t would be minimal, most likely of no practical importance. But, in the name of accuracy in the description of the tests, it should be z, not t.
You also mention $\chi^2$ tests. But in a comment, you say you are running a series of 2x2 tests. 2x2 $chi^2$ tests are not appropriate, because they assume that both samples could be subject to sampling errors. But in all your tests you compare to the million observations, which is the full population; there is no uncertainty about that proportion.
Now, you could still run a $\chi^2$ test (i.e. a test which follows a $chi^2$ distribution, but for that, the "expected counts" would be exactly the counts observed in the full one million observations population, and not the weighted average of the 2 observed counts!
And if you did it the way I just mentioned, lo-and-behold, you would obtain the exact same p-value as you would from a z-test of 2 proportions (because, in that scenario, the $chi^2$ statistic is exactly the square of the z statistic).
Then you also mention a binomial test you run. It is not clear what this test is? Fisher exact? 2x2 Fisher-exact tests would have the same problem of treating the "ground truth" as another (much larger) sample, and thus allocate some uncertainty to it (which it does not have). But a binomial test on the probability of observing whatever counts are in your 3 samples, if the "true porpotion" was what the one million observation population is would work; you are comparing an observed proportion to a known proportion.
So, TL:DR, a z-test or a binomial test, both comparing to the true proportion in your population are both valid, and given your large sample sizes, should give you very similar results. 2x2, or larger, contingency tables are not, as they assume that the population is just another sample subject to sampling errors. Nor are t-tests.
Now, why your results do not agree is yet another matter. If you could share the observed proportions (it is only 4 numbers), and the test results, then we could try analyzing them, and see what we get...
